# How to overwrite(reset) the default behaviour of SIGUSR1?

Tags: c, signals

I read about add signal() function in the signal handler function can over write the default behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void signalHandler();
int main(void) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);
    sleep(60);
    printf("I wake up");
    return 0;
}
void signalHandler() {
    signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);// I add this line to overwrite the default behaviour 
    printf("I received the signal");
}
```

And I trigger it with another process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    kill(5061, SIGUSR1); // 5061 is the receiver pid, kill(argv[1], SIGUSR1) doesn't working, when I get 5061 as parameter
    puts("send the signal ");
    return 0;
}
```

The receiver process `wake up` as soon as it receiver the `SIGUSR1` signal. How can I make the  receiver continue `sleep` even when it receive the signal from other process?

BTW why  `kill(5061, SIGUSR1);` 5061 is the receiver pid, `kill(argv[1], SIGUSR1)` doesn't work, when I get 5061 as parameter?

Comment: "`kill(argv[1], SIGUSR1)` doesn't work" -- Sorry, but C isn't Perl ... strings and numbers aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question (why `kill(argv[1], SIGUSR1)` does not work) actually is not related to signals, but to basic C programming. Please compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (i.e. all warnings and debugging information) on Linux, and improve your code till no warning is given.

Please read carefully the [kill(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) man page (on Linux, after installing packages like `manpages` and `manpages-dev` and `man-db` on Ubuntu or Debian, you can type `man 2 kill` to read it on your computer). Read also carefully [signal(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signal.2.html) and [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man pages. Read these man pages several times.

Then, understand that the kill syscall is declared as

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

and since `pid_t` is some integral type, you need to convert `argv[1]` (which is a string, i.e. a `char*`) to some integer (and `kill(argv[1], SIGUSR1)` should not even compile without errors, since `argv[1]` is not some integer but a string). So please use:

```
kill((pid_t) atoi(argv[1]), SIGUSR1);
```

The man page says also that you should use `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_DFL)` to restore the default behavior, and `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN)` to ignore that signal.

Of course, you should better use [sigaction(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) as the man page of `signal(2)` tells you.

At last, please take the habit of reading man pages and spend hours to read good books like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/). They explain things much better than we can explain in a few minutes. If you are not familiar with *C programming*, read also some good book on it.

Comment: He is using that in the last sentence of the question.

Comment: +1 for great explanation. and pointing out the important of geting the  habit of the man reading technique. and thanks for the great book you recommended

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch since type of `pid_t` is int , can I use `kill((pid_t) atoi(argv[1], SIGUSR1)` without typecasting?

Comment: I forgot a closing parenthesis (which I just added). But `(pid_t) atoi(argv[1])` *is* a typecast!

Answer (score 5):

From the [`sleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) manual page:

> **Return Value**
>
> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.

So instead of just calling `sleep` you have to check the return value and call in a loop:

```
int sleep_time = 60;
while ((sleep_time = sleep(sleep_time)) > 0)
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it before, but you could use [sigaction(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead and set the `SA_RESTART` flag, this should make syscalls restartable.

**Edit**:
Actually this won't work, according to the man page of [signal(7)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal%207) not all system calls are restartable:

> The sleep(3) function is also never restarted if interrupted by a
>   handler, **but gives a success return: the number of seconds remaining
>   to sleep**.

So you should call the `sleep` function again with the remaining time instead.